# Baggage wrapping in Warsaw, Poland

Tags: luggage, warsaw

Is there any baggage wrapping facility in Warsaw Chopin Airport?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, according to [iFly Terminal map](http://www.ifly.com/warsaw-airport/terminal-map) it's located on departures level. And in this [official Facebook post](https://m.facebook.com/LotniskoChopina/posts/805757946130791) (may be outdated though), the price is mentioned to be 50 PLN (around 12 EUR).